# Extract multiple elements in an Arrow proc context

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I want to parse the following sample XML file, without the pickler module.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Groups> 
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <GroupA>
        <Name>Foo</Name>
        <Sum>100</Sum>
    </GroupA>
    <GroupB>
        <Name>Bar</Name>
        <Sum>0</Sum>
    </GroupB>
</Groups>
```

I ended up with this:

```hs
{-# language Arrows #-}

import Text.XML.HXT.Core

data Groups = Groups GroupA GroupB deriving Show
data GroupA = GroupA String String deriving Show
data GroupB = GroupB String String deriving Show


readGroup :: LA XmlTree Groups
readGroup = deep (isElem >>> hasName "Groups") >>> getChildren >>>
  proc root -> do
    a <- readGroupA -< root
    b <- readGroupB -< root
    returnA -< Groups a b

readGroupA :: LA XmlTree GroupA
readGroupA = isElem >>> hasName "GroupA" >>> getChildren >>>
  proc root -> do
    n <- isElem >>> hasName "Name" /> getText -< root
    s <- isElem >>> hasName "Sum"  /> getText -< root
    returnA -< GroupA n s

readGroupB :: LA XmlTree GroupB
readGroupB = isElem >>> hasName "GroupB" >>> getChildren >>>
  proc root -> do
    n <- isElem >>> hasName "Name" /> getText -< root
    s <- isElem >>> hasName "Sum"  /> getText -< root
    returnA -< GroupB n s
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. 
If I try to extract just a single element in a `proc` context it works.
But trying to extract multiple elements will always fail\ return the empty list. I might have a misunderstanding of the composition `>>>`.

I run the example with `runLa (xreadDoc >>> readGroups)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```hs
readGroup :: LA XmlTree Groups
readGroup = deep (isElem >>> hasName "Groups") >>>
  proc root -> do
    a <- getChildren >>> readGroupA -< root
    b <- getChildren >>> readGroupB -< root
    returnA -< Groups a b

readGroupA :: LA XmlTree GroupA
readGroupA = isElem >>> hasName "GroupA" >>>
  proc root -> do
    n <- getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "Name" /> getText -< root
    s <- getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "Sum"  /> getText -< root
    returnA -< GroupA n s

readGroupB :: LA XmlTree GroupB
readGroupB = isElem >>> hasName "GroupB" >>>
  proc root -> do
    n <- getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "Name" /> getText -< root
    s <- getChildren >>> isElem >>> hasName "Sum"  /> getText -< root
    returnA -< GroupB n s
```

When the call to `getChildren` is outside the `do`-block, you are committing to one child before even entering the `proc`. Inside the `proc`, you check (for instance) whether that child has name `Name` *and* name `Sum`. Unsurprisingly, you don't find any child fitting these contradictory requirements.

By moving `getChildren` inside, you allow different children to be traversed for (for instance) `n` and `s`.